# Angular - dealy function call until Subject is not finished

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a function which cancels running process with some `processId`. There is only one **if statement** before which checks whether you have a `processId` and if so then it calls `cancel()`.

```
if (this.processId) {
  //...
  this.processEngine.cancel(this.processId, this.entityUid).subscribe(
    ...
  );
} else {
  console.log('No active process to cancel');
}
```

When starting the process a loading screen is displayed with load animation and the **Cancel** button. Now there is a problem that for a very brief moment (mostly when throttling via dev tools) user can click on the **Cancel** and the `processId` has not yet been initialized and thus starting process is not cancelled.

There are is a `Subject` within the service which has a `processId` value set when process successfully starts and it's immediately completed afterwards.

```
private startSubject = new Subject<string | null>();
...
// inside start function
this.startSubject.next(processId);
this.startSubject.complete();
```

There is also a `BehaviorSubject` which is set to true when project started and it's running.

```
active: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

I extended the **if statement** with `this.active.value` but I can't figure out how to postpone cancel call until `startSubject` is not completed. I tried using it in debounce, but it doesn't work as expected and the cancel method is called with `undefined` leading to error.

```
this.processEngine.cancel(this.processId, this.entityUid).pipe(
  debounce(() => 
    return this.startSubject.asObservable()
  )
)
.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Use finally to run code when an observable completes. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/finalize.html

Comment: I think I can imagine how this might work, just to check. I have to keep `cancel` state if process is active and I have no processId, return from `cancel()` and once startSubject is finalized, call `cancel()` again if needed.

Comment: This didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your requirement correctly then this is what you want to achieve -

*Nothing should happen on click of "Cancel" button until `"processId"` is not null.*

If my understanding is correct then you can do the following -

```
//have a Behavior subject to track processId
processId$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

//create the cancel button click observable
this.cancelClick$ = fromEvent(this.button.nativeElement, 'click');

//have a notnull processid observable
//it will ensure that only not null value will be emited
const notNullProcessId$ = this.processId$.pipe(filter(processId => !!processId));

//compose above both observables
//What will happen - 
//If you click "cancel" button nothing will happen
//as soon as your processId is emitting non null value, and then user clicks cancel your cancel API will be called
//it is just a basic - You can now code your API not to do cancel if process is already cancelled etc...
notNullProcessId$.pipe(
                  switchMap((processId) => {
                    return this.cancelClick$
                               .pipe(
                                 switchMap(() => {
                                   return this.processEngine.cancel(processId, this.entityUid);
                                 })
                               );
                  })                      
                ).subscribe(cancelResult => {
                  //do whatever you want to do wth cancel result
                  console.log(cancelResult);
                });

//This function will be called by your consumer who sets the processId
emitValue(processId) {
    this.processId$.next(processId);
    this.processId$.complete();
  }
```

Let me know if it works in your scenario.

Comment: This looks promising, will try when back in work :)